# Как создать "базовый" компонент в vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, рефакторинг, crud, чистый-код

Есть у меня много страниц со списком элементов. Обращаются к некоторому api и отображают полученное, что-то вроде:

Шаблон:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>City</h1>
        <div>
          <div v-if="errored" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Произошла ошибка: {{ this.error_text }}</p>
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <div v-if="loading" class="alert alert-info">Loading...</div>
            <div v-else>
              <table class="table">
                <tr v-for="item in info" :key="item.id">
                  <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.verified }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
import ApiService from '@/services/api';

export default {
  name: 'City',
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
      loading: false,
      errored: false,
      error_text: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    makeReq: function makeReq() {
      this.loading = true;
      ApiService.post('/cityApi/all', {})
        .then((response) => { this.info = response.data.cities; })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.errored = true;
          this.error_text = ApiService.get_error(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.makeReq();
  },
};
</script>
```

И как-то я в последнее время задумался о том, что постоянно повторяю один и тот же бойлерплейт в подобных страницах:

1. В шаблоне всегда присутствует некоторая кастомная секция с таблицей, а остальную обвязку постоянно копирую, с этим заголовком и показом загрузки/ошибки
2. В коде у меня всегда есть одни и те же переменные loading, errored и expired с одними и теми же значениям - их хочется один раз объявить в каком-то базовом компоненте и добавлять только новые, если понадобится
3. Запрос то же абсолютно одинаковый всегда, отличается разве url'ом

В гайдлайнах по vue.js не сталкивался с разделами, которые бы помогли вынести весь подобный однообразный код в какие-то базовые компоненты и отнаследоваться. Как такое вообще можно сделать в vue?

Comment: Копайте в сторону миксинов. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics

Comment: @Дмытрык Спасибо за наводку! Я правильно понимаю, что с шаблонами ничего не сделать, миксины только для кода?

Comment: Да, миксины только для кода. Однако шаблон можно подключить по ссылке. Выглядит это так `<template src="./hello.html"><template><script></script><style></style>`

Comment: Почему бы просто не использовать слот для кастомного содержимого? https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: То есть, используя этот компонент как "обертку" для других.

Comment: Насчет наследования [компонентов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WZS3Wg8FBc)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пришёл к такой организации проекта.

В папке src/mixins создал BaseApiRequestMixin:

```
import ApiService from '@/services/api';

const BaseApiRequestMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      errored: false,
      error_text: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    request: function request(url, data, response) {
      this.loading = true;
      ApiService.post(url, data)
        .then(response)
        .catch((error) => {
          this.errored = true;
          this.error_text = ApiService.get_error(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
    },
  },
};

export default BaseApiRequestMixin;
```

И использую в компонентах:

```
<script>
import BaseApiRequestMixin from '@/mixins/BaseApiRequestMixin';

export default {
  name: 'City',
  mixins: [BaseApiRequestMixin],
  mounted() {
    this.request('/cityApi/all', { }, (response) => {
      this.cities = response.data.cities;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Это прям хорошо чистит код скриптов. Со слотами и подключением шаблонов пока не разбирался.

Из замеченных недостатков - Vetur ругается на то, что Property 'errored' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance', надо поправить .vscode/settings.json:

```
"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": false,
```

Спасибо всем за советы.