# Объекты для Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Возникла потребность написать объект(класс) называйте как хотите. 
чтобы от него наследовать другие экземпляры. т.е

На .NET/C# можно было бы сделать так не вдаваясь в подробности (условно)

```
class helper
{
  string name;
  int age;
   public helper(string name, int age)
   {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
   }
}
```

и уже от него создавать столько объектов сколько нужно с разными свойствами.

Отсюда вопрос можно ли сделать что-то подобное на js/Vue.js
Знаю что текущее состояние классов в js слегка удручающее.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969330/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-vue

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class
В es6 появились нормальные классы. Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров - то babel в помощь - сконвертирует в старый синтаксис.

Comment: да эт понятно, как это будет выглядеть с vue. допустим есть обьект  btn который увеличивает счетчик на 1. от него нужно наследовать еще 1 обьект который будет увеличивать счетчик не на 1 а на 2 допустим. 

я немного не понимаю как мне это сделать

Comment: В примеси перенести общую логику
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html